# dyld: Library not loaded: image not found(Library path issue) using Xcode(9.4.1)

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, xcode9.4

I am getting this issue when I copy project(compressed file) from other machine, Don't know whether the problem with the pods,simulator or library path(using 9.4.1 Xcode). I have tried all the possible solutions which are asked before in stack overflow but nothing worked out, Kindly let me know
any solution. Find the log below

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
Referenced from: /Users/Emp-ID/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/18197A69-41B8-4F30-8B2E-6CAE7A28B038/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4C835A57-3FBF-4EA3-B4FC-A220F53A709A/KPI.app/KPI
Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Try to reinstall pod again.

Comment: use command `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install`.

Comment: @ChanchalChauhan Thanks bro it worked